# Table with multi header

Tags: tables

I'm trying to obtain the following table where the first two rows are the headers

[image]

I'm using the following code but it doesn't work

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table, dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
     \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      | c |  c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
      \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Code Representation Approach}}&\textbf{Programming Languages} & \textbf{Code Tackling levels}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Deep Learning Approach}}\\ \hline
      Tree Based Approach   & Graph Based Approach & Token Based Approach & Others & & & DL Model & Others  \\ \hline
         AST & CFG & Word Embedding & ByteCode& C& Method Level & ANN & DBN \\ \hline
         & DFG& n-grams & ASCCI & C++& Statement level & RNN & NMT \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

After implementing this code the corresponding table was not matching, and the last column is hidden because the table is shifted too much to the right

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table, which begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}` and ln preamble load only necessary packages. Showed images of table doesn't contain numbers, why then you use `S` columns?

Comment: @Zarko Done dear, The code is already updated, and yes there are no numbers in the table

Comment: `tabular` does not accept a width argument. You probably wanted to use `tabular*` instead. You currently only declare 5 columns, but seem to use 8 of them. In order to make the code compilable, add the missing column specifiers.

Comment: @leandriis The code is updated but still doesn't work, the problem is "extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr"

Comment: Additionaly, the code is not compilable since the `siunitx` package, which defines the `S` column type is missing. Since your table does not contain any numbers, there is no need for `S` type columns (and the `siunitx` package) at all, so you might want to replace `S[table-format=2.3]` and `S[table-format=2.2]` with `l` or `c` depending on the expected horizontal alignment.

Comment: The error message you now get is caused by missing column specifiers. You use a total of 8 columns, but `l l  l]  *{2}{c}`  only declares a total of 5 columns (and contains a `]` that does not belong there). If you want 8 horizontally centered colums, you could try `*{8}{c}` instead of the previously quoted code.

Comment: @leandriis The question is updated now, because your appreciated modification work fine, but the shape of the table is not matching, and the last column is hidden now

Comment: Your table is simple to wide that can be fit to text width. (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options, your question is now actully duplicate to it). You have two options: (i) enable multi-line cells' contents, (ii) rotate table to landscape orientation.

Comment: Probably, you could split the table in half and present two halfs that contain 4 columns each or use an ertirely different, probably itemize-based approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could squeeze your table into the available textwidth by shortening column headers and by allowing linebreak in the longer table entries. Note, however, that I had to keep the `\scriptsize` font size.

[image]

In the following MWE, I also included the following two alternative approaches, in which I split up the table into two halves of 4 columns, each:

[image][image]

Lasty, I added an example on how one could present the same information using nested itemize lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize\normalfont}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{ | c |  c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
      \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bfseries\thead[t]{Code Representation\\ Approach}}&\smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{Programming\\ Languages}} & \smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{Code\\ Tackling\\ levels}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries\thead[t]{Deep Learning\\ Approach}}\\ \cline{1-4} \cline{7-8}
      \thead{Tree\\ Based}   & \thead{Graph\\ Based} & \thead{Token\\ Based} & Others & & & DL Model & Others  \\ \hline
         AST & CFG & \makecell{Word\\ Embedding} & ByteCode & C   & \makecell{Method\\ Level}    & ANN & DBN   \\ \hline
             & DFG & n-grams                     & ASCCI    & C++ & \makecell{Statement\\ level} & RNN & NMT   \\ \hline
             & ... &                             & ...      & ... &                              & ... & ...   \\ \hline 
             & ... &                             & ...      & ... &                              & ... &       \\ \hline 
             &     &                             & ...      & ... &                              & ... &       \\ \hline
             &     &                             &          & ... &                              & ... &       \\ \hline
             &     &                             &          &     &                              & ... &       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Code Representation Approach}}     \\ \midrule
      Tree Based    & Graph Based     & Token Based    & Others    \\ \midrule
      AST           & CFG             & Word Embedding & ByteCode  \\ 
                    & DFG             & n-grams        & ASCCI     \\ 
                    & ...             &                & ...       \\ 
                    & ...             &                & ...       \\ 
                    &                 &                & ...       \\ \addlinespace \midrule
      \smash{\thead[t]{Programming\\ Languages}} & \smash{\thead[t]{Code Tackling\\ levels}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Deep Learning Approach}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
                    &                 & DL Model       & Others    \\ \midrule
      C             & Method Level    & ANN            & DBN       \\ 
      C++           & Statement level & RNN            & NMT       \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            & ...       \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
                    &                 & ...            &           \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\thead{Code Representation Approach}}     \\ \hline
      Tree Based    & Graph Based     & Token Based    & Others    \\ \hline
      AST           & CFG             & Word Embedding & ByteCode  \\ 
                    & DFG             & n-grams        & ASCCI     \\ 
                    & ...             &                & ...       \\ 
                    & ...             &                & ...       \\ 
                    &                 &                & ...       \\ \hline
      \smash{\thead[t]{Programming\\ Languages}} & \smash{\thead[t]{Code Tackling\\ levels}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Deep Learning Approach}} \\ \cline{3-4}
                    &                 & DL Model       & Others    \\ \hline
      C             & Method Level    & ANN            & DBN       \\ 
      C++           & Statement level & RNN            & NMT       \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            & ...       \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
      ...           &                 & ...            &           \\ 
                    &                 & ...            &           \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Code Representation Approach
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Tree Based Approach
    \begin{itemize}
      \item AST
    \end{itemize}
    \item Graph Based Approach
    \begin{itemize}
      \item CFG
      \item DFG
      \item ...
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
    \item Token Based Approach
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Word Embedding
      \item n-grams
    \end{itemize}
    \item Other
    \begin{itemize}
      \item ByteCode
      \item ASCCI
      \item ...
      \item ...
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
    \item Code Tackling levels
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Method Level
    \item Statement level
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Deep Learning Approach
  \begin{itemize}
    \item DL Model
    \begin{itemize}
      \item ANN
      \item RNN
      \item ...
      \item ...
      \item ...
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
    \item Others
    \begin{itemize}
      \item DBN
      \item NMT
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \item Programming Languages
  \begin{itemize}
    \item C
    \item C++
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```